# How do you add a fadeIn - fadeOut transition to a swap image

Tags: javascript, html

I found out all sorts of ways of adding a nice fade transition to a rollover image, but none actually say how to apply the script to an html document

this is what I've got so far.. how can I add a fadeIn, fadeOut script to that? instead of just flicking from image to image

```
<img src="images/portfolio.jpg" alt="" width="155" height="150" id="portfolio" 
onmouseover="MM_swapImage('portfolio','','images alt/index-alt_12.jpg',1)"
    onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" />
```

Here's the whole part in the HTML doc.

```
<td colspan="2" rowspan="5" align="left" valign="top"><a href="portfolio.html"><img src="images/portfolio.jpg" alt="" width="155" height="150" id="portfolio" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('portfolio','','images alt/index-alt_12.jpg',1)"
    onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" /></a></td>
```

how do I isolate the 'index-alt_12.jpg' and create an ID tag for it? and where do I put that code?

Comment: post your javascript functions.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using mouseover and out, I assume you have only two images right?

You can do this without javascript.  It will still work in older browsers, but the animated fades will work only on webkit, ie10 and mozilla. Its only an issue if you must have this fade on older versions of IE.

What you can do is place two images, with one on top of the other.

For example - assuming this are positioned one on top of the other through css

```
<img class="imageA" src="a.jpg" />
<img src="b.jpg" />
```

On the css

```
.imageA {
   -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease;
   -moz-transition: all 300ms ease;
   -o-transition: all 300ms ease;
   transition: all 300ms ease;
   opacity: 1;
}

.imageA:hover {
   opacity: 0;
}
```

You can use the transitions to animate from any one css property to another as well. 
Instead of two images, the one below could also be a background image of the container as suggested below, yet still do it purely through css.

Comment: note that this solution will not work in IE8- because the opacity property is not fully supported.

http://caniuse.com/css-opacity

This method could be adapted to work in IE8- with the use of filter:alpha but that becomes a whole other issue.

Comment: this is just causing the image to just fadeIn from nothing. Im using dreamweaver, the 'swap image' behaviour, and I don't know how to assign an ID tag to the swap image, as it's that that needs to fadein/fadeout

Answer (score 0):

Are you using jQuery at all? If so, there's a nice solution for you! At the bottom of your HTML page (under where you include jQuery), you could use something like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#portfolio").mouseover(function() {
    $("#img1").fadeTo(200, 1); 
    // The above means take 200ms to fade to an opacity of 1.0 (fully opaque).
    $("#img2").fadeTo(200,0);
    // The above says the same thing, but for fading out
  });
});
```

If you play around with this a little, you can get them to switch back and forth depending on which is showing, but that's the general idea.

And voila! I know you're looking for a javascript answer, but jQuery is extremely helpful for stuff like this, and would highly recommend it to you.

Comment: Great, thanks this looks v. useful, however is jQuery a plugin that I need to install? Im not clued up as to what it is

Answer (score 0):

There are bugs around the way you are trying to do it with a hard coded image, but you can switch to CSS as a workaround.

First, I would set up a div and make portfolio.jpg the background image:

HTML:

```
<div id="portfolio"></div>
```

The CSS:

```
#portfolio {
    background:url('images/portfolio.jpg') no-repeat;
    height: 150px;
    width: 155px;
}
```

Here's a way to fade `#portfolio` out on mouseover,  swap in a new background image, then fade the div back in. Requires jQuery 1.0+

```
$('#portfolio').mouseover(function() {
    var self = $(this);
    self
        .fadeOut('slow', function() {
            self
                .css('background-image', 'url("images alt/index-alt_12.jpg")')
                .fadeIn('slow');
        });
});
```